# Can we 'do evil'?

Tags: grammar, verbs

On another post discussion has moved to what one can and cannot 'do'. We 'do our duty', we do our homework' and we 'do the washing-up'. But we cannot 'do dancing', 'do driving', or 'do charity'- or can we? What is it that determines what we can or cannot 'do'?

Comment: If one can do good, I don't see why one cannot do evil. But What determines the "doability" of a concept... Looking forward to answers :)

Comment: [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+evil&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20evil%3B%2Cc0) says we certainly USE the idiom

Comment: Google states that they will 'Do No Evil'

Comment: Avast evildoers!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the other post mentioned, so I can read the context before I try to answer this (very short and very broad) question?

Comment: Ah, I think [this might be](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/158929/15299) the one?

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, that's the one.

Comment: "While I can vent clamor from my throat I'll tell thee thou dost evil." Particularly if thou shouldst venture to do Goneril behind Albany's back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Do*** is a very special verb that participates in innumerable idioms, fixed phrases, and constructions.

It's the default auxiliary verb, totally meaningless, inserted when an auxiliary is needed for a rule
like Negative-Placement, Negative-Contraction, Subject-Auxiliary Inversion, or Tag Formation:

- *Bill likes honey ~ Bill **does** not like honey ~ Bill **doesn't** like honey*
- ***Does*** Bill like honey? ~ Bill likes honey, **doesn't** he?

But that's not the *do* we're talking about here.

Then there's emphatic stressed *do*, as in

- *He **does** live in that building, I tell you!*

But that's not the *do* we want, either.

**This** *do* actually has a meaning, though only a very general one.
It  means the predicate `ACT`, in the sense of 'cause something to happen by performing an action'.
This *do* is a pro-verb that can be used to substitute for an active verb phrase; but it **must** be active.

- *What I told him to **do** was [to rent the house/to buy cookies/to be honest]*
- **What I told him to do was [to own the house/to want cookies/to be tall]*

*Rent the house, buy cookies,* and *be honest* are **active** verb phrases. They describe actions.
*Own the house, want cookies*, and *be tall* are **stative** verb phrases. They describe states.
That's why the second group of sentences above are ungrammatical. Action *do* requires active VPs.

The construction being asked about is a **transitive** action *do*: *do **something**.*
The question then is:

> What can be "something"?

The answer is:

> Any word or phrase that can be interpreted as an active verb phrase can be "something".

For example, a direct object may invoke a verb:

- *They do shrimp in lobster sauce very well here*. *do* = 'prepare, cook'
- *On this tour, she will do Chopin only*.   *do* = 'perform, play'
- *She never does the cobwebs in the corners.*  *do* = 'perform, clean'

or a noun may refer to a related verb:

- *She does the skiing well, but not the shooting*. *do* = 'perform, ski; perform, shoot'
- *I've never done accounting, only my taxes*. *do* = 'perform, bureaucratize'
- *He's going to do the summation.*  *do* = 'perform, summarize'

The default indefinite object of transitive action *do* is a construction with *thing*.
Note, however, that these "things" are always actions, not material things.

- *He did something funny to the onions. ~ Did you do anything funny to the onions?*
- *The things he's done would fill a book. ~ The things he was told to do would fill another.*

and if it is obvious that some *thing* is intended, it may be deleted like any indefinite.

- *He always does good things. ~ He always does good.*

but notice that this is not normally possible, except [generically](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html):

- *He does good **=** He always does good.*
- *He did a good thing at 3:48 this morning*. but * *He did good at 3:48 this morning*.

As to what "good" and "evil" mean, in these or any other contexts, consult your local philosopher.
It **is** certain, however, that in English one can grammatically, if only generically,
*do good* and *do evil*.

Comment: Thanks, John, for going to such lengths with this. I have learned, but I am still unsure as to why I can 'do some walking', but cannot 'do walking'?

Comment: _Do some walking_ is quantified; it's the same as 'walk a bit/some'. No reason not to use a _do_ construction to hang the quantification on. On the other hand, _do walking_ only makes sense in a context where there's something to contrast with, like _do shooting_ in a pedestrian biathlon. There's already a verb that does the job without adding an auxiliary verb and a suffix to it to mean the same thing.

Comment: I'd probably say 'Let's go walking/swimming', as an alternative to 'Let's do some walking'. So is 'go' an auxiliary verb?

Comment: It's what's called a "small verb", meaning [it forms serial constructions with verbs or verbal nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57776/15299) like _do_. But it's not quite an auxiliary yet; it hasn't been totally bleached of meaning.