# Can I use "will" as non-auxiliary verb?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english, auxiliary-verbs

I was in England and I heard that some people use word "will" as non auxiliary verb, in meaning "wish". Have I misheard? If it is true, in which cases can I use "will" as non auxiliary verb?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Keep in mind, however, that the past tense is then *willed*, not *would*.  An idiom that contains this non-auxiliary usage is *to will (something) into existence.*  Keep in mind that it does not mean *wish*; to wish for something is to cry into the wind for it, so to speak, whereas to will something is to make it happen by your own ingenuity.

Comment: Wow! It's really interesting! But I don't understand the meaning of "to will (something) into existence"? Can you explain or give more examples? Thank you.

Comment: *To will (something) into existence* is usually used sarcastically, to say that more thought than action is being put into something: e.g. *he's trying to will his fortune into existence.*

Comment: @kris - please refer to a good dictionary for the use and definition of will as a verb,  the following can help:  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will

Comment: Kris, I asked a [question about will](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161230/make-of-that-what-you-will-meaning-of-will) which might help explain the difference (or confuse you even more!)

Comment: Thanks to all those responded to my question and thanks for examples of real using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will has two distinct meanings as a transitive (non-modal, non-auxiliary) verb. The Merriam-Webster Dictionary lists one, but not the other. I found the other in the British version of Cambridge Dictionaries Online (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/will_10), although from my experience the meaning is as common in American English as in British English. Here is the dictionary's definition:

will
verb (MAKE HAPPEN)    /wɪl/
› [+ obj + to infinitive ] If you will something to happen , you try to make it happen by the power of your thoughts : She willed her self to remember his name .

› [I or T] formal to want something: Stay or go, as you will.

These are the two meanings in which you can use 'will' as a non-auxiliary verb (the second use being the same one as mentioned in the Merriam-Webster Dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will) has it as the first-mentioned use:

> transitive verb
>   :  desire, wish

That said, it is obviously most often used as an auxiliary verb.