# What word means 'willingness to learn'?

Tags: synonyms

What adjective (single word) means 'having/using a willingness to learn'?

Comment: Studious or erudite or receptive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you're looking for a single adjective, and I think "curious" fits the bill nicely (and from a pedagogical perspective curiosity is a key indicator of learner success) but I would like to add the following to the mix because I think it shows, if not willingness, at least readiness or capability, and it might be worth something to you:

**fertile mind**

From Collins:

> *fertile mind:* One that is capable of sustaining, supporting, growing and developing mental thought interjection, especially among the very young.

Answer (score 5):

How about *curious*?

> - having a desire to learn or know more about something or someone
> - marked by desire to investigate and learn
> - eager to learn or know; inquisitive.

Or inquisitive ^

Answer (score 3):

Having a willingness and capacity to learn is **teachability**:

> teachable  adj.
>
> 1. Capable of being taught: teachable skills.
> 2. Able and willing to learn: teachable youngsters.
>
> teach′a·bil′i·ty, teach′a·ble·ness n. teach′a·bly adv.
>
> American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.
>   Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.
>   Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights
>   reserved.

Answer (score 2):

Three excellent non-idiomatic words have already been suggested, curious, inquisitive, and teachable, but my intuition is that English lacks a word with your precise definition.

**I believe that the idiom "thirst" is what you are seeking.** "Thirst for knowledge" is a borderline cliche, but it is still evocative and clear, and I think many people would define it as a "willingness (or desire) to learn". (For the close connection between "will" and desire" see the interesting discussion, [“Make of that what you will” – meaning of “will”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161230/make-of-that-what-you-will-meaning-of-will).)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single word in English that would fit. Generally, "eager to learn" would be used.

Answer (score 1):

"Enthusiastic" is the best word that comes to mind for me. Doing is sort of like learning, so it is similar enough.